# How can I check whether a specific integer exists in an array column I'm selecting?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to run a query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT matches.*, array_agg(match_users.user_id)::int[] AS user_ids FROM "matches"
  INNER JOIN "match_users" ON "match_users"."match_id" = "matches"."id"
  WHERE (1 = ANY(user_ids))
GROUP BY matches.id
```

The `matches` have a many-to-many relationship with `users` (through the `match_users` join table), and I'm basically trying to find all the `matches` that a given `user` belongs to (in this case, the user with the ID of 1).

But I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR:  column "user_ids" does not exist
LINE 15:     AND (1 = ANY(user_ids))
                      ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "user_ids" does not exist
```

I'm sure there's something simple I'm missing here... Do I need to do something differently with my alias?

EDIT: Could I fix it with a sub select? The following seems to work, although I'm not sure it's doing exactly what I want without a lot more dummy data and testing:

```
SELECT matches.*, count(match_users.id) AS num_users, array_agg(match_users.user_id)::int[] AS user_ids FROM "matches"
  INNER JOIN "match_users" ON "match_users"."match_id" = "matches"."id"
  WHERE (1 = ANY(SELECT id FROM users WHERE users.id = match_users.user_id))
GROUP BY matches.id
```

I'm also not sure it will be very performant... it seems like this would be an awful lot of sub-selects if there were enough rows.

Comment: try to add an alias: AND (1 = ANY(match_users.user_ids))

Comment: @Almazini, do you mean instead of `AS user_ids`, try `AS match_users.user_ids`? I don't think it will let me choose an alias with a `.`

Comment: no I mean to change your WERE clause ... WHERE (1 = ANY(match_users.user_ids))

Comment: That gives me the same error.

Comment: SELECT operates on what WHERE produces (more or less) so there is no `user_ids` array visible in your WHERE. You need to rethink your query, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Edited the question to try to make it a bit more clear. `matches` and `users` have a many-to-many relationship to each other through `match_users`, and the purpose of this query is just to find all the `matches` that are associated with a given user ID.

... I guess I could fix the problem with a sub-select? That seems like it would become a very expensive query very quickly, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT m.*, array_agg(mu.user_id)::int[] AS user_ids
FROM "matches" m INNER JOIN
     "match_users" mu
     ON mu."match_id" = m."id"
GROUP BY m.id
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN mu.user_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```

In other words, you don't have to look in the array for the check.  You can just look at the returned value.

Comment: D'oh, I totally forgot about `HAVING`. Still a SQL n00b. I bet this will work, will try when I get home, thanks.